# Restrict cipher suites on JRE level

Tags: java, jce

Our Java application exposes a lot of different interfaces (SMTP, FTP, HTTP), secured by SSL/TLS. The goal now is to limit cipher suites allowed on these interfaces to include only "strong" ones. I already have a list and it's clear how to make it working for a particular socket

```
socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(ENABLED_SECURE_CIPHER_SUITES);
```

or for Tomcat connector

```
 <Connector port="443" ciphers="..."/>
```

The problem is that there are already 5 places in the application where I should apply this limitation manualy. Common SocketFactory does not seem to help, as it's not always feasible to supply custom SocketFactory to third-party API or framework. Is it possible to somehow introduce this limitation on JRE level, e.g. with JCE providers configuration or policy file?

JRE: Oracle JRE 1.7.0_17

Comment: Define 'strong'. Java already restricts the enabled cipher suites. Are you aware of the [Networking Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html)?

Comment: This question is not about the strength of a particular ciphers. I have a fixed list of allowed ciphers and I can't change it. For example, RC4 is not allowed at all. So, default Java restrictions aren't enough. I also checked networking properties, but found no properties related to cipher suites.

Comment: See the JSSE Reference Guide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I managed to get that working. Thanks to EJP for pointing in the right direction.
Since Java 1.7 there are two additional properties in $JRE_HOME/lib/security/java.security:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2
```

Controls algorithms for certification path building and validation.

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD5, SHA1, RC4, RSA keySize < 1024
```

JVM-wide algorithm restrictions for SSL/TLS processing, the one I was looking for. Notation is quite obvious here; it's possible to disallow certain algorithms or limit key sizes. Both properties are supported in Oracle JRE 7, Open JRE 7 and (surprisingly) [IBM Java v7](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/java7sdk/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.security.component.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/disabledalgorithms.html)